# I have a problem to submit inputs in one shot (php html mixed )

Tags: php, html

I made a form to get a number (quantity ) from the users ( number of samples to be tested ) , then I made a form for the users to enter comments regarding each sample , 
this works , but I don't succeed to send these comments in another php file with only one submit at the end  either to echo them and or to send them in mysql .
To do this I opened a new form just after the loop to submit at the end of the total entries and not after each one . This is the problem I think 
Thank you very much for solution

```
$i=1;
while ($i<= $_POST["quantity"]):
$quant = $_POST["quantity"]; ?>
<form>
    echantillon n° <?php echo $i ?>  <input type="text" name="trekking" >

</form>

<?php $i=$i+1;

   endwhile;

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="essaibg4.php" method="POST"> 
   <input type="submit" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML can't start before `<html>` tag. Also you can submit only one form at the time. Consider using `$_SESSION` or Ajax. Also note that you can have array of inputs with `<input type="text" name="trekking[]" >`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you attempting to use the same PHP file to print a form, then submit back to the same page and print output based on the posted value?

As @Justinas said, you have HTML outside of the <html/> tags but I'd also like to point out that there's no input with the name quantity or logic to handle it if it's not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to keep the  tags out of the loop. You only need one pair of those, and several  tags. And there are few things to move around. I haven't tested it but it should work. You had all the peaces of the puzzle but they were not appearing in the same order.

You code becomes ...

```php
<html>
<body>
<form action="essaibg4.php" method="POST"> 
<?php
  $i=1;
  $quant = (int) $_POST["quantity"];
  while ($i <= $quant): ?>

  echantillon n° <?php echo $i; ?>  <input type="text" name="trekking[]" >

  <?php $i=$i+1;

  endwhile; ?>

  <input type="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer , when I click on "submnit" I get "9 array array array array array array array array array "

essaibg4.php is :

```
<?php

echo $_POST["quantité"];
$x = 1; 

while($x <= $_POST["quantité"]) {
  echo   $_POST["trekking"] ;
    $x++;
} 

?>
```

thank you for new help ( if you could also give me hints for storing trekking values in mysql it would be great , I am a beginner in programming and dealing with html php python mysql is a bit confusing )

Comment: I also tried 'trekking' and "trekking[]" without success